# PayPal-PHP-SDK - error occur when testing with online server (IIs)

Tags: php, rest, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm going to integrate payment gateway using PayPal-PHP-SDK and I could test that api on my local server (wamp) correctly. But when I going to testing it with online server(IIS) I can't connect with paypal. No error messages shows on the browser. And I could find the place on the code when that happens.

`try {
$payment->create($apiContext);  <------ Can't do that !
}`

Can't we use this [PayPal-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) with IIs server ?

Can any one say how to fix this issue?

Comment: It should work fine, you need to check your error logs if no errors are showing, then enable error reporting, it could be you not got curl installed. Which version of PHP is installed?

Comment: It's PHP 5.4 I tried to enable error reporting  using web.config file. but I couldn't get any error. And also I tested this on  Apache server and it works fine on Apache.

Comment: Put: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of the script. Also complete the catch code, as its hiding the error you get from the lib.. `try{$payment->...} catch (\Exception $e){die($e->getMessage());}`

Comment: I added error reporting and catch code. But still I can't find an error. However thank you very much for your help. I don't know why only IIs server cant work this.